# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to build a JSF application, but I'm having this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: When does this Exception occur? Which container do you use? How does your facelets code look like?

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.descriptor.JspConfigDescriptor

This class was [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor.html) in Servlet 3.0. This error thus means that your webapp's runtime classpath is littered with arbitrarily downloaded JAR files from a completely different servletcontainer make/version which doesn't support Servlet 3.0, while the webapp is in turn deployed to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. This would only result in classloading conflicts in all colors because multiple different versioned classes exist in the runtime classpath.

Littering `/WEB-INF/lib` folder with servletcontainer-specific JAR files is in turn a common starter's mistake in a wild attempt to "fix" compile errors they faced in their IDE. This should have been solved differently. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/)

In a nutshell: Never put arbitrarily downloaded servletcontainer-specific JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Instead, configure your IDE project to set the desired target servletcontainer as "Target Runtime".